# Angular 6: provide func in new class constructor

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm sorry if it's a duplicate of someone question. However I can't find solution for my problem.

I have an Angular 6 app. And I made a service (*not injectable*).

I need to create a new instance of service, then make some magic inside and then call function outside. But when I return a value to a function to component I can't see component's variables. Here is an example of code:

**example.component.ts**

```
import { Calculation } from './calculation.service';

export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
    test: 1;
    potatoes: 2
    calculation: Calculation;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.calculation = new Calculation(this.doExternalMagic, this.potatoes)
    }

    doExternalMagic(potatoes: number) {
        console.log(potatoes);  // 3
        console.log(this.test); // undefined
    }
}
```

**calculation.service.ts**

```
export class Calculation {
    // i'm not sure that doExternalMagic should have type of Function
    constructor(private doExternalMagic: Function, private potatoes: number) { }

    public init() {
        this.potatoes = this.potatoes + 1;
        this.doExternalMagic(this.potatoes);
    }

}
```

I also tried make a `doExternalMagic` as a public in `Calculation` constructor but result is the same. Seems I do something wrong when I provide my func in service. How can I provide it properly to make magic outside in component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass your function as an arrow function:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.calculation = new Calculation((potatoes) => this.doExternalMagic(potatoes), this.potatoes)
}
```

Or use `bind()`. The problem is the `this` keyword context.